# How to create a list view using an exisitng view in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: list, sharepoint, listview

In a Sharepoint 2010 site, I have to create a new view using an existing view using code/programmatically. Please help me how to achieve this.
The existing view in the site includes columns, groupby, filters, sort etc. I have to include all these in my new view also.

Answer (score 0):

You can clone the existing view by using

```
SPView.Clone(Name, rowlimit, paged, default);
```